# Ext js 4 change textfield inputType dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is this possible? I want to change the password field to show the password when a checkbox is checked. I have searched the docs and haven't found a correct method. 
I have tried the following without success:

```
this.getPassword().inputType='text';
this.getPassword().getEl().dom.type ='text';
```

Comment: Please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719855/how-to-show-hide-password-in-ext-form-textfield

Answer (score 3):

Although it is possible, it is too much work because there are listeners installed on the input field so you should first uninstall listeners, then remove the input element, insert new input element, re-install the listeners and adjust size.

Much easier is to have two fields: password and text, programmatically sync their values and show/hide them on the checkbox click.

Answer (score 0):

We can change text input type dynamically with little code.

```
var userinput = document.getElementById('PasswordField');
userinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
ELEMENT.inputEl.dom.type = "password";
```

First, define inputType on the element, then change dynamically is JS.